# Can you keep the mail in Godaddy and the web in Google Cloud Computing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a domain in Godaddy, there we manage our company emails and so far the website and an internal administration system, we want to pass the web and the system to an instance of Google Cloud Computing, we know how to change the Godaddy NameServers to pass to Google as indicated on the following page https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart. Our question is; If changing the Nameservers, will mail continue to work with Godaddy? We want it to remain that way. Should I follow some extra step for the mail after changing the Nameservers?

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods (choices):

- Leave your dns servers at GoDaddy and change the A and CNAME records for your website to point to your new services at Google.
- Move your DNS records to Google Cloud DNS.

The first method is the easiest, the lowest amount of work and has the least risk. You just change the A and CNAME records that point your domain name to your new Google services.

The second method involves creating a new DNS Zone at Google Cloud DNS, duplicating each record that you have at GoDaddy (except for the NS and SOA records) and then switching the NS records at your domain registrar to point to your name servers at Google Cloud DNS.

Email does not care where you host your DNS servers. Email uses MX records. Provided that you accurately duplicate your MX records to your new DNS server, you will not have any problems except this can take as long as several days for the changes to go around the world. DNS server cache their entries so any changes you make takes time for the current entries to expire. This is called TTL (Time To Live).